# 64 bit Java is not installing properly

Tags: java, installation, minecraft, bukkit

Now I am not a very experienced programmer or computer person, so sorry if this is a repetitive problem that experts encounter here.

So I have a Bukkit Minecraft server that I am wishing to expand, here is the code that I am using to run the server: (In a .bat)

```
java -Xmx1.5G -jar bukkit.jar
```

From what I can tell, the -Xmx1.5G is is the maximum amount of memory that my server is allowed to use. When I expanded it to 2 G, it told me I could not allocate enough space, or in some similar wording. I did some light research and I discovered that there was some sort of limit on the amount a 32 bit Java installation could handle.

So, I uninstalled the 32 bit version of Java, and I re-installed the 64bit version. (I know that I am using a 64 bit computer) When I go to Program Files (x86), though, I do not see a Java folder. Now also I am seeing the error 'java is not recognized as an internal or external command'. I tried adding Java to my system path, and no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of the 32bit `Program Files (x86)` folder try the one without x86. Your question is also not programming related and better off at e.g. [su]

Comment: Oh man, really sorry. I knew something was off when I was posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 bit java isn't in "Program Files(x86)" because "Program Files(x86)" is for 32 bit programs. Try looking in "Program Files" instead.